# Change column datatype from NChar to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to change a column's datatype from `nchar` to `date` in SQL Server.

I have a column `dealdate nchar(16)` which stores data like this: `'2020-08-13'`

I need to change this column's datatype to `DATE`.

When trying to change, I get an error:

> can't change DATE from nchar

I try to use this command

```
ALTER TABLE [dbLedger].[dbo].[tblPurchBook] 
    ALTER COLUMN  DealDate DATE NULL;
```

Comment: 1) Do not store dates as strings.

Comment: *"2)NCHAR is deprecated"* no it isn't @Ilyes . `NCHAR` isn't even mentioned in [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (note that 2019 brought no new deprecations).

Comment: @Larnu Yup, my bad that was NTEXT.

Comment: Is that the actual error message? I can see a possible conversion error due to non-conforming date values but I don't think "can't change DATE from nchar" is a valid SQL Server error message.

Answer (score 1):

Validate the date values first using `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
select dealdate
from [dbLedger].[dbo].[tblPurchBook] pb
where try_convert(date, dealdate) is null and dealdate is not null;
```

If this returns any rows, then you need to fix the values before you can change the type.

One method is to set the bad values to `NULL`, which you can do with:

```
update [dbLedger].[dbo].[tblPurchBook] pb
    set dealdate = null
    where try_convert(date, dealdate) is null and dealdate is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see tried about it. but I have not solved.

"ALTER TABLE [dbLedger].[dbo].[tblPurchBook]
ALTER COLUMN  DealDate DATE NULL;"

This command used MSSQL V18.6
I got an error on this.

"ERROR MESSAGE
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
문자열을 날짜 및/또는 시간으로 변환하지 못했습니다.
문이 종료되었습니다.
(cannot convert charator to date or time
did closed statement)

Completion time: 2020-08-19T11:38:06.5978013+09:00"

Is there other way?

Thanks